# Still confused by Objective C variable scope

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to get some employee data from a JSON service. I am able to get the data and load it into an NSMutableArray, but I cannot access that array outside the scope of the method that gets the data.

TableViewController h filed

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "employee.h"

@interface ViewController : UITableViewController

{
    //NSString *test;
    //NSMutableArray *employees;
}

@end
```

And here is my m file:

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
#define scoularDirectoryURL [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://xxxx"]

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{

        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        scoularDirectoryURL];

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}


- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {

    NSError* error;
    NSMutableArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
    id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSMutableArray *employees = [[NSMutableArray alloc  ]init];
    if (!jsonArray) {

    } else {

        for (jsonObject in jsonArray){
            employee *thisEmployee  = [employee new];
            thisEmployee.fullName   = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"$13"];
            thisEmployee.state      = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"state"];
            thisEmployee.city       = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"city"];
            [employees addObject:thisEmployee];
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Bryan

Comment: In Objective-C, it is standard convention to capitalize the first letter of a Class. This will make your code much more readable to other ObjC developers, especially on SO

Comment: Thank you. I am learning the conventions and want to follow them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were on the right track. All you have to do is uncomment the NSMutableArray declaration in your @interface, and then change this line:

```
NSMutableArray *employees = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

to this

```
employees = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Declaring the array in your interface will allow it to be accessed from anywhere within your implementation, or even from other classes and files if you declare it as a public property. When you make a declaration inside a function, that variables scope does not extend to outside of the function.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I get it. I didn't understand exactly the difference between declaring and instantiating it. I was in essence declaring the array twice, but with different scopes. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just to elaborate a little on the scope of the variables, you have several ways of declaring them. The most used are:

1. Instance variables, which are declared in your interface and they can be accessed from any method inside the class or inside any method from it's subclasses. For example:

> ```
> @interface MyObject : NSObject { //this can be any class
>   NSString *instanceVariable;
> }
>
> @implementation MyObject 
>
> -(void)someStrangeMethod {
>    instanceVariable = @"I'm used here";
>    NSLog(@"%@",instanceVariable);
> }
>
> //from subclasses 
> @interface MySubclassObject: MyObject {
>    //see that the variable is not declared here;
> }
> @implementation MySubclassObject
>
> -(void)anotherStrangeMethod {
>   [super someStrangeMethod]; // this will print the value "I'm used here"
>   instanceVariable = @"I'm changing my value here"; //here we access the variable;
>
> }
> ```

2. If you want the instance variable to be accessed only from the "owner" class you can declare it after the `@private` tag. You also have the `@protected` tag,  though that isn't used so much.

If you want to have a variable that can be accessed outside the class, declare it as a property in your interface.

Also you can make the properties private using `@private` but this will contradict the purpose of the properties.

Comment: This is also very very helpful. StackOverflow kicks ass.